# How do I get back plain Unicode characters in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: fonts, 18.04

I performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 over 16.04, keeping my `/home` partition. I use i3 exclusively.

Now there are those new colorful emojis. Looks aside (blerg), unfortunately, the coverage of unicode symbols seems to have been reduced quite a bit. For instance, consider this part of my i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+1 workspace 1:
bindsym $mod+2 workspace 2:
bindsym $mod+3 workspace 3:
bindsym $mod+4 workspace 4:
bindsym $mod+5 workspace 5:5
bindsym $mod+6 workspace 6:6
bindsym $mod+7 workspace 7:7
bindsym $mod+8 workspace 8:8
bindsym $mod+9 workspace 9:
bindsym $mod+0 workspace 10:
```

[That's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZDIv.png) a 3/6 ratio -- ugh.
For reference, the one for workspace 2 is [Back of Envelope U+1F582](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F582/) -- nothing too exotic, I think.

Removing `fonts-noto-color-emoji` as advised by [dobey](https://askubuntu.com/users/50737/dobey) *does* remove the color emojis in i3 (not in Firefox) but now none of the six unicode characters above show up (in i3bar, vim, ...):

[image]

So how can I go back to clean unicode symbols without frills? Can I keep the Ubuntu font or will have I have to change system font completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing the Symbola font does the trick:

```
sudo aptitude install fonts-symbola
```

This *seems* to be the font I used on 16.04 but it's of course hard to be sure.